# How to write a function with lifetime constraints for fields?

Tags: rust, parameters, lifetime, borrow-checker

In the example below, I have a lifetime constraint for the `one` member. The first call to `set_one` works, however a second call doesn't:

```
struct One {
    name: String,
}

struct Two<'a> {
    one: Option<&'a One>,
}

fn set_one<'a>(two: &'a mut Two<'a>, one: &'a mut One) {
    one.name = "something".to_owned();
    two.one = Some(one);
}

fn main() {
    let mut one = One { name: "".to_owned() };
    let mut two = Two { one: None };
    
    set_one(&mut two, &mut one);
    set_one(&mut two, &mut one); // error: "two" already borrowed!
}
```

[Playground here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf942370515ed5cbfa90d110e98d4517).

My understanding is that after the first call to `set_one` the ownership is given back to the original caller, so when the function returns the borrow for `two` is gone. But apparently I'm missing something.

What's wrong with the lifetimes of the example above?

Comment: [Your issue can be simplified down to much shorter code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6038b4fd18b943413fca93bc3a1fafac).

Comment: The first issue is that you enforce that `&'a Two` and `Two<'a>` have the same lifetime, which extends the borrow. This can be fixed by changing it to `&mut Two<'a>`. However, then you arrive at the more serious issue, which is that `set_one` assigns a reference of `one` to `two`. This will cause the subsequent `&mut one` to fail, as you can't mutably borrow `one` while `one` is already borrowed.

Comment: @Aplet123 your example fails due to the second issue mentioned in vallentin's comment.

Comment: @kaveh My example isn't supposed to compile: it's supposed to be a shorter example of the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

For this to make sense you need to recognize that there are 3 lifetimes involved in the calling of `set_one`

```rs
fn set_one<'a, 'b, 'c>(two: &'a mut Two<'b>, one: &'c mut One)
```

The lifetime of the reference `two` the lifetime of the reference `one` and the lifetime of the reference `one` within `Two`. These are `'a`, `'b` and `'c` respectively in the signature above.

When you write the signature as

```rs
fn set_one<'a>(two: &'a mut Two<'a>, one: &'a mut One)
```

You are forcing the 3 lifetimes to be the same. And to put it simply this forces these lifetimes to take the 'bigger' lifetime.

Examining the main function:

```
fn main() {
    let mut one = One { name: "".to_owned() };                       |
    let mut two = Two { one: None };                                 | Lifetime of 'a 
                                                                     |
    set_one(&mut two, &mut one);                                     |
    set_one(&mut two, &mut one);                                     |
}
```

We can see that implicitly now the struct `two` is a `Two<'a>` with the lifetime `'a` as marked in the code.

Then when we call `set_one` we force the lifetime of the three parameters to be `'a`.

You could declare the lifetimes as:

```rs
fn set_one<'a, 'b>(two: &'a mut Two<'b>, one: &'a mut One)
```

However, this has a problem which is at the root of what you want to do:

```rs
fn set_one<'a>(two: &'a mut Two<'a>, one: &'a mut One) {
    one.name = "something".to_owned();
    two.one = Some(one); // <--- This
}
```

When you do this `two.one = Some(one);` you need the reference within `Two` to live as long as `one`. Therefore, there is no escaping the fact that you can't call `set_one` twice because you will need 2 mutable borrows that will live as long as the scope of `one` in the main function.

Comment: You can set the lifetime of `&'a mut One` to `'b` too. This would fix the error in `two.one = Some(one);`.

Comment: @Kowalski If you do that you go back to your initial problem, 'b lifetime is the whole main function, so the second time you call `set_one` you are doing a second mutable borrow. Which makes sense, because the borrow inside `two` lives throughout all the main function.